# Can I have multiple Wi-Fi passwords so I can restrict access to one of them

Tags: wireless-networking

My wife has a home office and needs to be on Internet all day. I have 6 other people in the family that need Internet access but one of the kids has gone off the rails and needs his Internet restricted to an hour a day without affecting other users? Is it possible have multiple Wi-Fi passwords so I can restrict access to one of them?

I currently have a CenturyLink router connected to a Netgear router.

Comment: With the provided hardware, probably not... Which is providing your WiFi? (CenturyLink / Netgear). Do they both have WiFi? You might be able to use the two as separate access points...

Comment: Sounds like you are asking about a solution without really explaining the problem which is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you really want to restrict one of the kids access to the Internet, the best way to do that is with device level filtering (aka: MAC address filtering) so when that device is connected the user is restricted. But how to do that varies between router to router and might not even be possible as simply as you describe.

Comment: Can you share model numbers?

Comment: Sure, with a virtual AP, firmware permitting (some stock firmware does, otherwise custom like ddwrt). Some APs also let you set allowed times by MAC address (can be spoofed but kids probably don't know).

Comment: @JakeGould At least they included the end goal.

Comment: The Netgear router will have a parental controls area, likely you can configure a schedule per device.

Comment: What are the model numbers of the routers please? RADIUS/EAP would allow you to have individual username/passwords, and restrictions per user or device. It must be supported by the firmware the router is running.

Answer (score 1):

You can use your modem's administration panel to restrict the access of that child. Most panels have built-in parental controls, and not knowing what model your router is, I can't tell you if either of yours does or does not have parental controls in its' firmware.

NetGear offers an app that may be compatible with your setup to institute parental controls and such:

https://www.netgear.com/home/discover/apps/lpc.aspx